# Installing an app from Android Studio has timed out

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

Since we migrated to modules we started experiencing a time out when installing the application for the second time. It only happens if we run the app for the second time. If we clear the project (`Build->Clean Project`) it launches ok, but the next time we try to run, it times out.
I have looked at the Android Studio logs and found an error that is thrown when launching the app but I am not sure what could go wrong and how to interpret these logs. Here is the snapshot of the logs:

```
    2021-01-19 12:26:15,790 [413000061]   INFO - ools.idea.run.tasks.DeployTask - Installing application: ***** 
2021-01-19 12:26:15,792 [413000063]  ERROR - intellij.openapi.progress.Task - entry 
java.lang.NullPointerException: entry
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getInputStream(ZipFile.java:361)
    at com.android.tools.deployer.ApkParser.getApkDetails(ApkParser.java:88)
    at com.android.tools.deployer.ApkParser.parse(ApkParser.java:107)
    at com.android.tools.deployer.ApkParser.parsePaths(ApkParser.java:76)
    at com.android.tools.deployer.ApkInstaller.deltaInstall(ApkInstaller.java:244)
    at com.android.tools.deployer.ApkInstaller.install(ApkInstaller.java:91)
    at com.android.tools.deployer.Deployer.install(Deployer.java:145)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.tasks.DeployTask.perform(DeployTask.java:119)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.tasks.AbstractDeployTask.run(AbstractDeployTask.java:119)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.LaunchTaskRunner.run(LaunchTaskRunner.java:191)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:932)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcessWithProgressAsync$5(CoreProgressManager.java:434)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$null$3(ProgressRunner.java:233)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:166)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:627)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:572)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:61)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:153)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$4(ProgressRunner.java:233)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1604)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021-01-19 12:26:15,798 [413000069]  ERROR - intellij.openapi.progress.Task - Android Studio 4.1.1  Build #AI-201.8743.12.41.6953283 
2021-01-19 12:26:15,799 [413000070]  ERROR - intellij.openapi.progress.Task - JDK: 1.8.0_242-release; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
2021-01-19 12:26:15,799 [413000070]  ERROR - intellij.openapi.progress.Task - OS: Windows 10 
2021-01-19 12:26:15,799 [413000070]  ERROR - intellij.openapi.progress.Task - Last Action: Run 
2021-01-19 12:26:46,303 [413030574]   INFO - j.ide.actions.RevealFileAction - Exit code 1
```

Please, help.

Comment: ReInstalling Android Studio solved this for me, so try that , or try updating AS

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help.

Comment: @RubenMeiring I solved the issue, take a look at the answer if you are interested, and thanks again for your help.

Comment: Aah yes,that probably why reinstalling android studio solved my issue because the gradle version changed with the reinstall, PS. I had a similiar issue recentely where i actually had to Downgrade my gradle version,just something to think about when you get an error like ths in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to different versions of Android Studio and Android Gradle Plugin. When I had updated the Android Gradle Plugin version to the last available version the issue was gone. For more info see the posted issue in [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/177918178).